# How to convert numbers to be a comma separated value in Klaviyo

Tags: javascript, formatting, number-formatting, data-conversion

I have these dynamics variables which has a number.

```
I.E) 1, 10, 350, 1200 or 12500, etc.
```

On Klaviyo I want to format these numbers to be comma separated if it's over 1 thousand.

```
I.E) 
      1200 -> 1,200
     13499 -> 13,499
   1000000 -> 1,000,000
```

If it's less than 1 thousand, there are no commas

```
     5 -> 5 
     60 -> 60
     100 -> 100
```

I tried looking for a Klaviyo Filter here https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058466052-Glossary-of-Variable-Filters
but there are none specific for converting number to comma separated thousands.

I can't seem to find the right filter and I'm not sure how to write a custom one to do this.

How would we do this in Klaviyo?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if Klaviyo intends this to work, but surprisingly, in my test it did!

Klaviyo's templating engine, as you pointed out, is based on Django's Template system - but Klaviyo can determine what functionalities are enabled (or disabled) or install custom ones.  One of these filter libraries is called "[django.contrib.humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/humanize/)" which adds these "human touch" to data.

To do this, you first load the library like this:
`{% load humanize %}`

Then you can use the filter `intcomma` like this:
`{{ your_variable|intcomma }}`

Testing this with:

```
{{ 1000000|intcomma }}
```

Yields:
`1,000,000`

Try it and let us know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Sadly I no longer have access to Klaviyo, I was using a Typescript and JS based code repo and not Django so I'm not sure if that would be compatible. Hopefully this helps someone though!